# How do I perform a slice effect like Fruit Ninja?

Tags: android, cocos2d

I want to do slice effect like in Fruit Ninja. Is there any class in Cocos2D like CCBlade? How can I use the CCBlade in Cocos2D on Android?

Answer (score 2):

CCBlade https://github.com/hiepnd/CCBlade

There is an example provided with the project. Don't know what more you could wish, except for somebody making your game.

Comment: That code is in Objective-C. It would need to be translated to another language for Android use.

Comment: The conditions are different for android.